# Is there any way to rename or change the gender of my hero?

Tags: diablo-iii

I created my hero in a fit of sleep deprivation and named him something I now regret.  I can't find any way of changing the hero options I set when I first created my hero, though.

Is there any way to rename my hero, now that I've invested some time in his training, and I feel like I could more properly title him?

Also, while I'm at it, can I change his (her?) gender?

Comment: Keep in mind that unless you're taking screenshots, nobody is going to see your heroes name anyway.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Can't you see other player's names in multiplayer?  I've only soloed so far.

Comment: Nope, you're only shown their battletag - not the name of the individual hero they're playing.

Comment: Unless they've said anything recently (character name shows up in chat)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz you can see their character's name if you mouse over them in your friend's list, but not when you're actually playing with them. They also show up in dialog if you have subtitles on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, to change the name or gender you would need to delete and re-create the character.  However given the multiple character slots and the ability to have two characters with the same name, you can forego the deleting part if you want.